# two subsets whose union contains all the elements and intersection contains none of the elements

Tags: java, linked-list

A singly linked list int the same order in which they appear.Then with out changing the linked list , the program should print whether there exists a partition of the list (two subsets whose union contains all the elements and intersection contains none of the elements) whose sums,when XOR'd equals a target value. Example: -4 3 5 {{-4}{3,5},{-4,3}{5},{-4,5}{3},{-4,3,5}{0}} sums:{{-4}{8},{-1}{5},{1}{3},{4}{0}} Xor of sums:{-12,-6,2,4} assume the target is 2 and so it should print true.

```
enter code here
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.*;

public class Equal {
static int a;
  public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(new File("testing.txt"));
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    sc.useDelimiter(" ");
    LinkedList ll = new LinkedList();
    while (sc.hasNext()) {
      String s = sc.next();
      /*if (s.trim().isEmpty()) {
        continue;
      }*/
      int b=0;

          ll.add(b, s);


     // System.out.println(s);
    b++;
    }
   //System.out.println("Original contents of ll: " + ll);
    System.out.println(ll.size());
    sc.close();
   System.out.println("Enter an integer");
    a = in.nextInt();
    String d ;
    int e=0;
    int z=0;
   /* int[] binary = new int[(int) Math.pow(2, N)];
    for (int i = 0; i < Math.pow(2, N); i++) 
    {
        int b = 1;
        binary[i] = 0;
        int num = i, count = 0;
        while (num > 0) 
        {
            if (num % 2 == 1)
                count++;
            binary[i] += (num % 2) * b;
            num /= 2;
            b = b * 10;
        }

        if (count == 1) 
        {
            System.out.print("{ ");
            for (int j = 0; j < N; j++) 
            {
                if (binary[i] % 10 == 1)
                    System.out.print(ll+ " ");
                binary[i] /= 10;
            }
            System.out.println("}");
        }
    }*/
    sc.close();
  int N=ll.size();
    /*set_size of power set of a set with set_size
    n is (2**n -1)*/
     //double pow_set_size =Math.pow(2, N);
    int counter, j;

    /*Run from counter 000..0 to 111..1*/
    for(counter = 0; counter < N; counter++)
    {
    for(j = 0; j < N; j++)
    {
        if(counter!=j)
        {


            //System.out.println( ll.get(counter)+"{"+ll.get(j)+"}");
        }
        if(counter!=j)
        {
         d=String.valueOf( ll.get(j));

         e=Integer.parseInt(d);
         System.out.println("printing subset values "+e);
         if(counter==j)
         {
        z =z+e;
         }
        }
    }
    String b=String.valueOf( ll.get(counter));
    int f=Integer.parseInt(b);

    int g=e-f;

    if(g==a)
    {
        System.out.println("true");
    }

    }
  }

  }
```

Comment: It isn't clear what you are asking - what have you tried and what issues have you encountered?

Comment: A linked list with values -4,3,5 are present.These values should be divided {-4}{3,5},{-4,3}{5},{-4,5}{3},{-4,3,5}{0} as shown such that all the elements are present.Here add the elements in subset(EX:{3,5}={8}).Then it becomes {{-4},{8}}.Then xor EX:(-4-8=-12) and with out using another linkedlist or array.

Comment: But what have you actually tried? You need to try and code it yourself, and then if you run into any specific issues ask about those. SO is not a general code writing service.

Comment: Hi ajshort, I had just entered the code.It runs upto three elements in linked list .I need help if there are more elements.